# If $G$ is finite group how to prove that $f(g)=ag$, $a \in G$, is a bijection for all $g\in G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is finite group, how to prove that $f(g)=ag$, $a \in G$, is a bijection for all $g \in G$? Here $ag$ is $a \cdot g$, where $\cdot$ is the operator from the group $G$.

This is what I've tried so far:

$f(g)=ag
\\
a^{-1}g(g)=g. 
$

Since the inverse has been dotted so $f$ is a bijection, I would like to know if there's a misstep on that.

Comment: It is not true that $f(g)=g$ generally.  Note that, for $g_1\in G$, we do always have $f(a^{-1}g_1)=g_1$.

Comment: By definition, $f(g) = ag$; you cannot just insert $ga^{-1}g$ at will wherever you want and hope to maintain equality: $ga^{-1}g$ is not necessarily equal to the identity of $G$.

Comment: $g$ is the argument of $f$, so saying that $f$ is a bijection "for all $g\in G$" doesn't make any sense. It should be replaced with "for all $a\in G$".

Answer (score 3):

The inverse of $g\mapsto ag$ is simply $h\mapsto a^{-1}h$.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $a\in G$.

Define

$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}: G&\to G,\\
x&\mapsto a^{-1}x.
\end{align}$$

Then for any $g\in G$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(f\circ \hat{f})(g)&=f(\hat{f}(g))\\
&=f(a^{-1}g)\\
&=a(a^{-1}g)\\
&=(aa^{-1})g\\
&=eg\\
&=g\\
&={\rm id}_G(g),
\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
{\rm id}_G:G&\to G,\\
x&\mapsto x
\end{align}$$

is the identity function on $G$. But $g$ was arbitrary. Hence

$$f\circ \hat{f}={\rm id}_G.$$

Similarly,

$$\hat{f}\circ f={\rm id}_G.$$

Thus $\hat{f}$ is the inverse of $f$.

Hence $f$ is a bijection.

---

*Note:* We did not use the fact that $G$ is finite. It is irrelevant. Indeed, such an $f$ is always a bijection for any $G$ and any $a$.

Comment: where surjectivity come from?

Comment: It's implied by the existence of an inverse, @DaviAmérico. I suggest you revise the definition of "bijection".

Answer (score 1):

Though the claim holds true for any group, you can take advantage of the assumed finiteness of $G$ to get immediately:

1. the injectivity holds by the left cancellation law;
2. since $G$ is finite, the surjectivity follows from 1.